# Facebook Page Insights API and limiting objects

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I've succeeded at accessing a Page's insights via:
https://graph.facebook.com/{pageID}/insights

I've even managed to limit the response with this tag:
{pageID}/insights/page_fans/lifetime

... however, this query doesn't seem to work (even though the data *is* present in the base /insights response):
https://graph.facebook.com/{pageID}/insights/page_posts_impressions/week

... it returns no data. What am I doing wrong? Do I need different app rights? (I'm currently using scope=read_insights,offline_access,read_stream,manage_pages.) It seems expensive to request the entire insights response when I only need a single element.

thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use FQL to target just the item you're interested in. See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/

```
SELECT metric, value 
  FROM insights 
 WHERE object_id=111605505520003 
   AND metric='page_like_adds' 
   AND end_time=1272351600 
   AND period=86400
```

Comment: FQL is deprecated; how do you do this in the Graph API?

Comment: FQL is dead (Facebook's choice, not mine)... please respond as per the request, regarding the Graph API.

Comment: FQL is not dead nor is it currently being deprecated.

Comment: well, blessed be you sir, I'm a SQL nut, so hearing that FQL is alive and well is a joyful thing indeed. A couple of you brought this distinction to me attention, thanks to you both. SQL lives!  ;)